# Datatype problem with ADO pulling for CSV

Tags: sql, csv, types, ado

Ok, running into a problem with pulling a Zip code from a CSV file using ADO.  Whats happening is that if the first set of zip codes are 5 digits long, the datatype is assigned as an integer for the whole field property in the recordset which wouldn't be a problem if the following zip codes weren't the 9 digit zip code with the dash (99999 vs 99999-9999). When these 9 digit zip codes are encountered, the field yields a null.  So, I can only assumet that JET 4 takes a small sample of the data (first 3 records?) and assigns the datatype to that field.  Ive tried setting the field type during runtime, but failed either because I don't know what I am doing or its beyond my control.

A couple of note worthies:
1. I have control of the SQL statement that pulls the info (which uses a group by clause)
2. I have limited control before the data is pulled in.
3. The runtime language VB6 using ADO.

Any suggestions or pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ADO does type coercion based on the first record. Dash '-' is an invalid character in an integer type, so it won't parse them. You want the entire thing to be a string (Really, you do- zip codes are strings, not integers).

It might be worth it to preparse the data. Write a small program to read the CSV and add -0000 to the 5-digit records. Then all records will be 10 digits, with a -, and *should* be coerced to a string.

Comment: Hmmm, any way to make the datatype assignment to the field as string before the data is loaded into ADO?  Adding the extended -0000 is doable, but not the optimal solution.

Comment: I'd have to know more about your setup. Assuming you're just passing the csv filename to ADO, I can't think of any place to add callbacks before ADO actually reads it, though someone with more ADO experience than myself may have a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the common way to do this is using a [Schema.ini file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> When the Text driver is used, the
>   format of the text file is determined
>   by using a schema information file.
>   The schema information file is always
>   named Schema.ini and always kept in
>   the same directory as the text data
>   source. The schema information file
>   provides the IISAM with information
>   about the general format of the file,
>   the column name and data type
>   information, and several other data
>   characteristics. A Schema.ini file is
>   always required for accessing
>   fixed-length data. You should use a
>   Schema.ini file when your text table
>   contains DateTime, Currency, or
>   Decimal data, or any time that you
>   want more control over the handling of
>   the data in the table.

I set up an example using the following files:

**test.csv**:

```
normal text,12345
some more ordinary words,12345-9876
```

**Schema.ini**

```
[test.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=Dummy Text
Col2=ZipCode Text
```

**test.vbs**

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oConn : Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rs : Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim scriptPath : scriptPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & scriptPath & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO"""

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM test.csv", oConn

WScript.Echo rs.Fields(0).Name & "|" & rs.Fields(1).Name

Do Until rs.EOF
    WScript.Echo rs.Fields(0).Value & "|" & rs.Fields(1).Value
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
oConn.Close
```

And the output looks like:

```
Dummy|ZipCode
normal text|12345
some more ordinary words|12345-9876
```

Keep in mind that the Schema.ini file must be in the same folder as the text file and must refer to the text file by name (`[test.csv]` in the example above).  You may have to dynamically generate the Schema.ini file for each file you import, or make a copy and rename of the csv file to a temporary location.